# A simple way to Iterate on XML tree and extract data from it?

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

Assuming that I have four levels in my XML tree , where level 3 can have the same son - twice , i.e. 
in the following XML :

```
<Game>
    <Round>
        <roundNumber>1</roundNumber>
        <Door>
            <doorName>abd11</doorName>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>0</xVal1>
                <xVal2>25</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.31</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>25</xVal1>
                <xVal2>50</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.04</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>50</xVal1>
                <xVal2>75</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.19</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>75</xVal1>
                <xVal2>100</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.46</pVal>
            </Value>
        </Door>
        <Door>
            <doorName>vvv1133</doorName>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>60</xVal1>
                <xVal2>62</xVal2>
                <pVal>1.0</pVal>
            </Value>
        </Door>
    </Round>
    <Round>
        <roundNumber>2</roundNumber>
        <Door>
            <doorName>eee</doorName>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>0</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-25</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.31</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-25</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-50</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.04</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-50</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-75</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.19</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-75</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-100</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.46</pVal>
            </Value>
        </Door>
        <Door>
            <doorName>cc</doorName>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-60</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-62</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.3</pVal>
            </Value>
            <Value>
                <xVal1>-70</xVal1>
                <xVal2>-78</xVal2>
                <pVal>0.7</pVal>
            </Value>
        </Door>
    </Round>
</Game>
```

I have two `Doors` for each `Round` , then the question is , using `Dom` or `Sax` (or Jdom if it helps) can

I iterate on my tree and get the data in every level ?

At the moment I "went" a level down and got the Rounds , here :

```
  DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("input.xml"));

    // normalize text representation
    doc.getDocumentElement ().normalize ();
    System.out.println ("Root element of the doc is " +    // would produce Game
         doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());


    NodeList roundNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("Round");   // roundNodes are the Rounds 
    int totalNodes = roundNodes.getLength();                   // 2 by the example 
    System.out.println("Total number of Rounds are : " + totalNodes);   


    for (int i = 0; i < roundNodes.getLength() ; i++)

    {
        Node node = roundNodes.item(i);
        if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
        {
            Element element = (Element)node;
            NodeList firstDoorList = element.getElementsByTagName("Door");
            Element firstDoorElement = (Element)firstDoorList.item(0);

            NodeList textFNList = firstDoorElement.getChildNodes();
            System.out.println("First Door : " + ((Node)textFNList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
        }
    }
```

but it seems a lot of code for iteration .

Is there a simple way to extract the data of that XML ? assume that I have 2 Doors per round and someK number of Rounds .

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Parsing content like this is one of the reasons I wrote [SJXP](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/simple-java-xml-parser-sjxp/) -- I know, I know "Oh god, not another home-brewed library!", but don't despair, it is an easy-to-use library built ontop of the STAX parser spec so you get none of the overhead that you do with DOM with all the ease of XPath. I built it as the result of hand-writing feed parsers (RDF, RSS, ATOM) for more than a year and realizing the more complex my work got, the more similar it all was so I distilled down the core tenants into a single, simple and fast library (the overhead is less than a SAX parser -- it also runs on Android with no added dependencies).

The gist of the library is defining a series of rules targeting all the elements in your XML that you want. Given that all of your XML data you want to parse is CHARACTER data (not attribute data from inside the tags) you would define a series of character rules like so:

```
IRule roundNumRule = new DefaultRule(Type.CHARACTER, "/Game/Round/roundNumber") {
    @Override
    public void handleParsedCharacters(XMLParser parser, String text, Object userObject) {
        System.out.println("Round Parsed: " + text);
    }
}

IRule doorNameRule = new DefaultRule(Type.CHARACTER, "/Game/Round/Door/doorName") {
    @Override
    public void handleParsedCharacters(XMLParser parser, String text, Object userObject) {
        System.out.println("Door Name: " + text);
    }
}
```

... and so on -- paths for your other rules would look like this:

- /Game/Round/Door/Value/xVal1
- /Game/Round/Door/Value/xVal2
- /Game/Round/Door/Value/pVal

After you had all your rules, you would create an [XMLParser instance](http://thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/sjxp/javadoc/com/thebuzzmedia/sjxp/XMLParser.html) like so, giving it all the rules you created:

```
XMLParser parser = new XMLParser(roundNumRule, doorNameRule, <more rules>);
```

Then you use it to parse your XML by feeding it any valid *InputStream* instance that represents a stream of XML via one of the [parse methods](http://thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/sjxp/javadoc/com/thebuzzmedia/sjxp/XMLParser.html#parse%28java.io.InputStream%29).

You can safely reuse the XMLParser instance over and over again (just not in separate threads at the same time).

You will need to keep track of your state in so much as you know which roundNumber you are loading Door values for and which Door you are populating with which values, but that is easy enough to do -- just create simple Java POJOs to represent your structure and store them in an ArrayList, for example:

```
List<Round> roundList = new ArrayList<Round)();
```

Say your "Round" POJO looked like this:

```
public class Round {
    public int number;
    public List<Door> doorList;
}
```

and your Door POJO looks something like:

```
public class Door {
    public String name;
    public int xVal1;
    public int yVal2;
    public double pVal;
}
```

The top level *roundList* would represent the root of the parsed values and you could pass that directly into the parse operation; that is your *userObject* you see referenced in the SJXP Javadocs.

What will happen is when a rule matches, it passes that userObject through to the rule, so you'll have access to that list you passed in.

In the case of the roundNumRule -- you'll create a new Round POJO, assign it the roundNumber value and add it to the list.

In the case of the doorNameRule -- you'll pull the last Round from the list, add a new Door POJO to it and assign its name to it.

And so on...

I hope that helps!